# Write Generic Swift Method to load data from property list

Tags: ios, swift, generics, functional-programming

I have a method that loads an array of dictionaries from a propertylist. Then I change those arrays of dictionaries to array of a defined custom type; 
I want to write that method in generic form so I call that method with the type I expect, then the method loads it and returns an array of my custom type rather than dictionaries

```
func loadPropertyList(fileName: String) -> [[String:AnyObject]]?
{
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "plist")
    {
        if let plistXML = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(path)
        {
            do {
                if let temp = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(plistXML, options: .Immutable, format: nil) as? [[String:AnyObject]]
                {
                    return temp
                }
            }catch{}
        }
    }

    return nil
}


//

func loadList<T>(fileName: String) -> [T]?{//**Here the answer I am expecting**}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your function to read from a Plist works and that you don't want to subclass `NSObject`.

Since Swift reflecting does not support setting values this is not possible without some implementation for each Type you want this to work for.

It can however be done in a pretty elegant way.

```
struct PlistUtils { // encapsulate everything
    static func loadPropertyList(fileName: String) -> [[String:AnyObject]]? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "plist") {
            if let plistXML = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(path) {
                do {
                    if let temp = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(plistXML, options: .Immutable, format: nil) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                        return temp
                    }
                } catch {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This protocol will be used in a generic fashion to get the Type name and read the corresponding Plist.

```
protocol PListConstructible {

    static func read() -> [Self]

}
```

This protocol will be used to implement Key Value setters.

```
protocol KeyValueSettable {

    static func set(fromKeyValueStore values:[String:AnyObject]) -> Self

}
```

This is the combination of both to generate an array of objects. This does require that the Plist is named after the Type.

```
extension PListConstructible where Self : KeyValueSettable {

    static func read() -> [Self] {
        let name = String(reflecting: self)
        var instances : [Self] = []
        if let data = PlistUtils.loadPropertyList(name) {
            for entry in data {
                instances.append(Self.set(fromKeyValueStore: entry))
            }
        }
        return instances
    }
}
```

This is some Type.

```
struct Some : PListConstructible {

    var alpha : Int = 0
    var beta : String = ""

}
```

All you have to do is implement the Key Value setter and it will now be able to be read from a Plist.

```
extension Some : KeyValueSettable {

    static func set(fromKeyValueStore values: [String : AnyObject]) -> Some {
        var some = Some()
        some.alpha = (values["alpha"] as? Int) ?? some.alpha
        some.beta = (values["beta"] as? String) ?? some.beta
        return some
    }
}
```

This is how you use it.

```
Some.read()
```

Comment: thanks ,Xcode playground accepted it,  I never saw this "Self" before but I need to review protocol oriented programming

extension PListConstructible where Self : KeyValueSettable